# How to make bootstrap modal with a js work on multiple websites independent from the unique styles?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

for multiple websites, with unique styles I need to write a JavaScript. This script needs to create some popovers and a modal window. The popovers and modal should look an all pages the same. For the popovers I set

```
data-container="#myContainerID"
```

Then I am append to the body

```
<div class="my-bootstrap-iso" id="myContainerID"></div>
```

The class "my-bootstrap-iso" contains all bootstrap css, but processed with http://lesscss.org/. And so far it works well. 
Now I wanted to do something similar with the modal. So I appended with js the class "my-bootstrap-iso" to the body when the modal opens and remove it when it closes. For some websites this works. But other websites are not adding the class "modal-open" to the body. And even if I append this class to the body when the modal opens, it doesn't work. But I don't want to write for every website a specific code for the modal. 
Is it possible to make the modal window look independent from the website style? If yes, how?

Hope someone can help.